# Test php mail function on your localhost

Tags: php, mail-server

I am not able to test `mail()` function on my localhost. I tried to find the same on web but did not succeed.

The main problem is with configuration of `ArgoSoft Mail Server`. Is there an alternative to that software?

Comment: Actually it is not programming question but a server setup one. And personally I don't understand why you all want to test mail() function locally on windows. Cannot get a live server for test or just delay testing a bit or what?

Comment: Using mail locally on Windows is a piece of cake, you just have to read the comments in php.ini and make the relevant changes (set SMTP to the mail server of your ISP or a local SMTP server, restart apache and hey presto, it works).

Comment: @WIMVDS: What kind of changes are you talking about....can u elaborate
?

Comment: You have to change the SMTP setting in php.ini, just search for SMTP, uncomment the relevant line and assign the FQDN of your SMTP server. Keeping in mind that this will not work when the SMTP server requires authentication (then you'll have to use some other means to send mail, because the mail function doesn't offer any support for SMTP authentication).

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP with Mercury Mail